# MySQL get the word that contains a substring

Tags: mysql, sql

How to list all words that contains a specific substring, for example:

I have the following table in my database

```
| id | title                                       |
| -- | ------------------------------------------- |
| 1  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text discovered |
| 2  | It is a long established fact that a reader |
```

When I search for `'re'` like:

```
SELECT 'WORD_THAT_CONTAINS re' AS title FROM myTable WHERE title LIKE '%re%'
```

It should return

```
| title      |
| ---------- |
| Lorem      |
| discovered |
| reader     |
```

Comment: Do you want the result from a query or is it ok to get it from a procedure?

Comment: [regex_substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) could help depending on your MySQL version. Do you need all fragments from the title?

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? What is **maximal** words per value? Does the words delimiter is space char only?

Comment: Your sample data shows strings consisting of words separated by single blanks. Is this guaranteed to be so or can there be other characters separating words (tabs, commas, groups of blanks, ...)? Please be aware that your table is not normalized, because you are not storing the separate words, but word lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### MySQL version 8+:

Using [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and I have assumed that the maximum word length here is `64`. You can change it if necessary

**Sample Data:**

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS sentences;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sentences
(
    sentence VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO sentences
VALUES ('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text discovered'),
       ('It is a long established fact that a reader'),
       ('This is also another test text');
```

**Query:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE w AS (SELECT cast(NULL AS CHAR(64)) AS word, t.sentence AS sentence
                     FROM sentences t
                     UNION
                     SELECT substring_index(sentence, ' ', 1) AS word,
                            substr(sentence, length(substring_index(sentence, ' ', 1)) + 2)
                     FROM w
                     WHERE length(sentence) > 0)
SELECT word
FROM w
WHERE word LIKE '%re%';
```

**Result:**

```
Lorem
discovered
reader
```

---

### MySQL 8-:

If your MySQL version doesn't support `CTE`, with a [Cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) and a [Temp Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) inside a [Stored Procedue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) with **the same sample data**:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sentenceToWord$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sentenceToWord()
BEGIN

    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE sent VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT sentence FROM sentences;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wordTemp
    (
        word VARCHAR(64)
    );

    OPEN c;
    WHILE NOT done
        DO
            FETCH c INTO sent;
            IF NOT done THEN
                WHILE length(sent) > 0
                    DO
                        SET @word = substring_index(sent, ' ', 1);
                        INSERT into wordTemp VALUES (@word);
                        SET sent =  substr(sent, length(@word) + 2);
                    END WHILE;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;

    CLOSE c;
    SELECT word FROM wordTemp WHERE word LIKE '%re%';
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE wordTemp;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL sentenceToWord();
```

Comment: Too expensive  (by memory consumption), especially on huge data. Generating the numbers list and extracting the word by its index may be less expensive.

Comment: I too think that this approach is somewhat expensive but it's handy as it is only one query. How about using a cursor and a temptable inside a stored procedure? what do you think of that? (performance-wise) @Akina

Comment: No-no... I mean generate numbers list in CTE and then use double SUBSTRING_INDEX for to extract single word by its number. Single query too. PS. Procedure with the cursor should be too slow while comparing with single query.

Comment: @Akina Did I get it right? I updated the answer.

Comment: No, I mean clear numbers generation. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0daa990fb6d3981d5ddd870f5d463f9

Comment: I like the original approach. Let's not forget that we are fighting a denormalized data model here (i.e. the data is not atomic in the sense of we are storing lists of words in strings when we are actually interested in the separate words). So the iterative approach with a recursive query going through the string until it is done with all the words, no matter whether these are ten words or hundreds, seems appropriate. If speed becomes an issue then the OP should reconsider the data model.

Comment: It's a good solution , but unfortunately my Database version doesn't support `WITH RECURSIVE`.  Is there any alternatives?

Comment: @ferhado I added another solution.

Comment: this answer is wonderful